# Как сделать pull to refresh только вверху списка

Tags: java, android, pulltorefresh

Все просто, когда я внизу списка и тяну сверху вниз, чтобы попасть наверх, у меня вылетает этот pull to refresh и мне не попасть наверх, только если сначала потянуть снизу вверх, и не отпуская руку резким движением потянуть сверху вниз (facepalm), как сделать так чтобы работал только если я вверху списка?

Comment: Какой pulltorefresh вы используете? Приведите разметку где это происходит и версии используемых библиотек.